# Wordpress post status change from published to draft

Tags: plugins

I created custom post type (I used geodirectory). 
I need, If somebody edit and save on frontpage, change from publish status to draft status.

It is possible?

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain more about your setup? Do you have a static Page set as the homepage, and when someone edits it you want the Page to revert to a draft and something else to show as the homepage? How does the CPT relate to publishing vs. draft? In general, you need to grant edit capability but not publish capability to any user where you want their edits to revert the content to a draft, but typically that doesn't mix with homepage behavior.

Comment: **A quick tip for getting great answers**: Consider starting by expanding on the summary you put in the title. Explain how you encountered the problem and any difficulties in solving it yourself. The first paragraph is the second thing most readers will see, so make it a good one. Check [our guide to asking good questions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) if you need to.